# How can I use code point of Bootstrap Icons?

Tags: css, bootstrap-icons

### Summary of the problem

The following image is a description of bootstrap icon.

I don't know how to use "Code point".

[image]

- Unicode: `U+F120`
- CSS: `\F120`
- JS: `\uF120`
- HTML: `&#xF120`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Using HTML code point, All you need is just set the the font-family of your element(or your body) to 'Bootstrap-icons' and then everything will work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.9.1/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
  <style>
    .test
    {
      font-family:'Bootstrap-icons';
    }
</style>
  <body>
    <div class="test">
      &#xF120
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to find how to use CSS of "code point".

Add following html into the head element of document.

Set `font-family` to be `Bootstrap-icons`.

And you can use css code point `\F120` to fill the value of `content` property.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<style>
    h3::before {
        font-family:'Bootstrap-icons';
        content:'\F120';
    }
</style>
```

The otheres (Unicode, JS, HTML) are still ununderstood.

Thank you for reading my broken English! :)

Comment: Please mark this as solved to help other that may come across this question and want an answer as well. It also stops this question from being recommended for answering.

Comment: This problem is still unsolved.